# System.UnauthorizedAccessException while writing a unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Hello I am building a chatroom system and was asked to write a unit test to it with Nunit. The "UserData" is currently stored in a .bin file. I wrote a test which registers a user and tries to login with its credentials. For some reason the test fails and throws an Exception saying that the access to the file is denied.

Here is the test i wrote :

```
        [Test]
    public void Login_Registered_User_Test() {

        ChatRoom cr = new ChatRoom();
        cr.Start();

        String username = "test123";
        String groupId = "5";


        Assert.AreEqual(true,cr.Register(username, groupId));
        Assert.AreEqual(true,cr.Login(username, groupId));

    }
```

and the exception is coming from here :

```
        private void createFile() {

        Stream stream = new FileStream(FolderName, FileMode.Create);
        stream.Close();

    }
```

> Message: System.UnauthorizedAccessException : Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\UserData.bin' is denied.

Comment: You probably have to specify the full (absolute) path to your data file. At the moment it's relative, and during test execution it's going to be relative to the location of the test runner, which in this case seems to be in the VS folder you listed.

Comment: The filesystem is a dependency that should be mocked out in your unit tests. You don't want a unit test to fail because a dependency isn't available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the visual studio is not able to access the Programfiles folder. Try opening the VS in Administrator mode and run the unit test .

Comment: Wow, thanks it worked. cant believe i havent thought about it xD